# Sentinel 2 preprocessing with R

Tags: r, remote-sensing, sentinel-2

I need to transform Sentinel 2 L1C imagery to preprocessed Level 2A data.
Ideally this should happen in R, as the remaining processing stack is already done in R.
Are there ready preprocessing solutions similar to [Sen2Cor](http://step.esa.int/main/third-party-plugins-2/sen2cor/)?

I already found the [`RStoolbox`](https://github.com/bleutner/RStoolbox), but it states to be intended for Landsat imagery. The same goes for [`satellite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/satellite/index.html).

Is athmospheric correction, cloud detection and other preprocessing specific to each satellite platform, or can I still apply the functions from these packages to Sentinel 2 data?

Comment: How about https://github.com/ranghetti/sen2r?

Comment: oh i forgot about that. I had issues installing it, and it depends on Sen2Cor. I was hoping for an R implemetation without external binary dependencies.

Comment: I don't think that you will be able to find what you are looking for. I have yet to see actual atmospheric correction happening systematically in R, without relying on external binaries, such as SNAP.